# Table View header get stuck when implementing pull to Refresh in Swift

Tags: swift, uitableview

I have a table view inside a `UIViewController`. I have implemented a `UIRefreshControl` on the tableView. If I drag the table up while the refresh controller wheel is spinning the first header gets stuck in the middle of the table. I can't figure out what is wrong...

Here is a screenshot of the problem:

[image]

Here is the code I used in `viewDidLoad`:

```
        refreshControl = UIRefreshControl()
        refreshControl.tintColor = UIColor.redColor()
        refreshControl.addTarget(self, action: "handleRefresh:", forControlEvents: UIControlEvents.ValueChanged)
        tableView.insertSubview(refreshControl, atIndex: 0)
        tableView.sendSubviewToBack(refreshControl)
```

And this is how I create the headers:

```
  func tableView(tableView: UITableView, willDisplayHeaderView view: UIView, forSection section: Int) {
        let header: UITableViewHeaderFooterView = view as! UITableViewHeaderFooterView //recast view as a UITableViewHeaderFooterView
        header.contentView.backgroundColor = UIColor(red: 59/255, green: 134/255, blue: 134/255, alpha: 1.0) //make the background color light blue
        header.textLabel.textColor = UIColor.whiteColor() //make the text white
        header.alpha = 0.5 //make the header transparent
    }
```

Thanks a lot !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using `tableView.addSubview(refreshControl)` should work fine and behave correctly. Check your storyboard, If you have no navigation bar then disable the "Extend under top X" options, if you do make sure they are enabled.

If it all fails, how are you creating your header views? If they are created & returned like regular cells in a table, like

```
let headerCell = tableview.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("HeaderCell") as! UITableViewCell
```

try to wrap them in an UIView before returning them

```
let view : UIView = UIView(frame: headerCell.view.frame)
view.addSubview(headerCell.view)
return view
```

Sometimes this issue occurs when table view treats those headers as a regular table cells and complains about lack of index paths for them screwing up the layouts.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion, I have tried your suggestions. It didn't work :( I am already wrapping the headers cells in an UiView as I am using `func tableView(tableView: UITableView, willDisplayHeaderView view: UIView, forSection section: Int)` ...

Comment: Well in that case I'd just use UITableViewController as it natively supports pull to refresh and it's actually the only way of doing this that apple says wont get deprecated/stop working later.

Answer (score 1):

You inserted the refresh control here:

```
tableView.insertSubview(refreshControl, atIndex: 0)
```

What you should do/have done:

```
self.tableView.addSubview(self.refreshControl)
```

Also, you need to write the code for HandleRefresh and trigger

```
refreshControl.endRefreshing()
```

at the end of the method. The way you wrote your code meant that you've added the control to a particular part of the table...

An alternative approach would be to enable the refresh control in StoryBoard. Be careful not to add both - i.e, enable it and create it yourself in code.

You can see both examples [here](https://www.andrewcbancroft.com/2015/03/17/basics-of-pull-to-refresh-for-swift-developers/)

Answer (score 0):

I know it's a bit late, but maybe this can help to other people still searching for the solution to this issue.

Since iOS 10, you can use [refreshControl](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiscrollview/2127691-refreshcontrol) property of the UIScrollView on your tableView.

```
tableView.refreshControl = refreshControl
```